# Answering Machine For Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to write an auto answering machine for android ? For example, When incoming call event occurs, this application starts to play voice.

how can i do this ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, not. You can write code which will handle incoming call and can accept call, but reliable solution for playing audio into call line does not exist.
See more info here: [Play pre-recorded audio into a voice call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776516/play-pre-recorded-audio-into-a-voice-call)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. It would require changes in Android at the platform level.